# Change height and width of static SVG string in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a static svg string "testImg" that I am working with in my React application

the `testImg` string looks like

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN\"\n \"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd\">\n<svg version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\n width=\"225.000000pt\" height=\"225.000000pt\" viewBox=\"0 0 225.000000 225.000000\"\n preserveAspectRatio=\"xMidYMid meet\">\n<metadata>\nCreated by potrace 1.16, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2019\n</metadata>\n<g transform=\"translate(0.000000,225.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)\"\nfill=\"#000000\" stroke=\"none\">\n</g>\n</svg>\n"
```

I am currently rendering this string using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, which I feel isn't ideal.

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: testImg }}></div>
```

My main issue though is, I want to change the size of the image being rendered. I have currently tried different variations of things like

```
 document.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("width", "20px")
```

Is there a way for me to resize this svg string being rendered?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?

```
import testImg from "./testImg.svg";
<img src={testImg} style={{ height: 40, width: 20 }} alt="Test Image"/>
```

Comment: No this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the svg a component and pass the height and width as props and import it to replace the div.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).